# whether have another method to select these node in css

Tags: css

How to select these nodes which I mark in the picture below

[image: picture]

That's my way of writing it, I want to know whether have another method

```
.m1 > div, .m2 > div, .m3 > div, .m4 > div{}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
div[class^="m"] > div {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

```html
<div class="m1">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
<div class="m2">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
<div class="m3">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
<div class="m4">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

You can use common selector for the classes starting with 'm'... Like below,

```
div[class^="m"] > div {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

You can also select any class containing a common word/character like below:

```
div[class*="m"] > div {
    background: #ffff00;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Give common class to all div's like this sample code I have done

```css
.m>div {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="m1 m">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
<div class="m2 m">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
<div class="m3 m">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
<div class="m4 m">
  <div>text</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't want to add another class